# Conditional CSS Class Based on Value of Number

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following HTML:

```
<td v-bind:class="getClass()" class="metric-cell vs-last-week">
{{ (((metrics.twitter.engagements.thisWeek - metrics.twitter.engagements.lastWeek) / metrics.twitter.engagements.lastWeek)*100).toFixed(1) + "%" }}
</td>
```

Is there a way to obtain the value within the cell so that I can process it in `getClass()` and change the color to green if it's positive?

I know I could likely create a method for the actual processing of data instead of the ugly inline expression and then use that to recalculate in getClass() and check positive/negative there, but I'd like to know if it's possible to grab the value from the `<td>` and then do a comparison without recalculating and return the proper class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically whenever I want to save a calculated value I just create a new scope. The method for doing that in Vue is a component.

```
Vue.component("metric", {
  props:["metric"],
  template:`
    <td :class="getClass()">{{metric}}</td>
  `,
  methods:{
    getClass(){
      return {
        green: this.metric >= 0,
        red: this.metric < 0
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then you can use that in your table like so:

```
<td is="metric" :metric="(((metrics.twitter.engagements.thisWeek - metrics.twitter.engagements.lastWeek) / metrics.twitter.engagements.lastWeek)*100)"></td>
```

Comment: This is working to populate data but the CSS class isn't being populated.

Comment: Working now :) Obviously can't do numerical comparison on a string with `%` appended.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to read if you move most of the complex calculations out of the template and into computed properties like this:

```html
<td :class="cssClass" class="metric-cell vs-last-week">
  {{ (vsLastWeek * 100).toFixed(1) + '%' }}
</td>
```

```js
computed: {
  vsLastWeek() {
    const thisWeek = this.metrics.twitter.engagements.thisWeek;
    const lastWeek = this.metrics.twitter.engagements.lastWeek;
    return (thisWeek - lastWeek) / lastWeek;
  },

  cssClass() {
    if (this.vsLastWeek > 0.9) {
      return 'some-class';
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: In your example, where is `this.vsLastWeek` being defined? What's the context of `this`?

Comment: `this` refers to the component instance from which you can access the data, props, computed properties and methods of that component. `vsLastWeek` is defined as a computed property which can be accessed like `this.vsLastWeek`. It's defined as a function, but you access it as a property of `this` (think of it as a "read only" data property).